# With twitter bootstrap should all my rows add up to 12?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering what best practice is here.  I'm making a form which has controls grouped via the `form-group` class.  This has controls grouped horiztonally for example title, forename, surname on one line, then the next line could have day, month, year inputs.

To achieve the three controls on one line I use the following markup:

```
<div class="form-group">                            
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="title" class="">Title</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="title" name="Title">
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="forename">Forename</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="forename" name="Forename" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="surname" name="Surname" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="dobDay">Date of birth</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dobDay" name="DobDay">
            <option value="-1">Day</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="dobMonth">Month</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dobMonth" name="DobMonth">
            <option value="-1">Month</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="dobYear">Year</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dobYear" name="DobYear">
            <option value="-1">Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above works, however I'm wondering if it's best practice to have all columns add up to 12 in the `form-group`, so in that case I'd group the date of birth fields in a `form-group`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

So it's okay to have more than 12 units in a row, it simply causes the overflowing `col-*` to wrap. When building responsive sites this allow for flexible layouts on different screen widths/devices. For example, you could go from 3 columns on medium widths, down to 2 columns on smaller widths..

http://bootply.com/qmT5hfIXSJ

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answers say about the general consensus about rows adding up to 12, the difference in implementation between having a row and not having a row is that a row is like a container unit. If a div isnt put in the row, then it will come after the row container that spans the width of the view. This is seen when you have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inside">in row</div>
</div>
```

With this, since theres 16 col widths in a row, 4 col widths wrap to the next line, yet still inside the row. So the next col width 4 in the second row div starts in the line 3 rather than "picking up where the other col 4 width div left off" in line 2.  You can see the difference in this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/61/

Essentially row divs are used for separate contents that you dont want other contents to "bleed" into or "mix" into.  Rows arent necessary for your code, but they can help delineate sections as separate from other sections

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought and this is how I hoped it would work.  Also - in the documentation, it states that a 'form-group' acts like a row when used within a 'form-horiztonal' and therefore do not require a 'row'

Answer (score -2):

a ROW is what adds up t 12
so if you want to use properly the col grids you should wrap them in a row div
like this:

```
<div class="form-group">  
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">some Content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise the classes col-sm* are not really being used

Comment: sorry but that's not technically correct.  In the documentation (here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), it states that a 'form-group' acts like a row when used within a 'form-horizontal' and therefore do not require a 'row'

Comment: this means it requires form horizontal which he didnt provide. so yes your comment is an alternative solution which both mine and yours are correct but dont say that is not correct just because there is another way